# Are there any game engines for iPhone?

Tags: iphone

Are there any game engines for iPhone?

Comment: There is also [NME](http://www.haxenme.org "NME")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two most popular are probably [Oolong](http://oolongengine.com/) and [SIO2](http://sio2interactive.com/DOWNLOAD.html) but for what it's worth, I recommend you do something like this:

- Sound: use CAF files and apple's own SoundEngine OpenAL wrapper class from the samples (beware, there are memory leaks in the example code you'll need to plug)
- Models: use [this wavefront OBJ loader](http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/wave_front_obj_textures_working) for obj and mtl files exported directly from Blender or Max
- Textures: use Apple's own Texture2D class from the samples (bmp will work, but I recommend png because of the platform optimizations)
- 'Engine' is really just the classes that glue this stuff together.  [This guy's doxygen](http://www.studiomike.net/doc/class_game_engine_1_1_base_game.html) seems kind of "textbook".  [This guy](http://alanmorey.com/moge/blog/archives/130) also has a decent example UML too (IMHO).

Personally I think it's all so subjective, you really should write this stuff yourself because it should be architected for the way you need it, not just something written that tries to be everything to everybody.

FYI, our team decided to do everything in Objective-C++, where the core of the game is written in C++  and there is a thin layer of Objective-C on top of it that glues the code to the UI widgets and such things.

Comment: I found a site that keeps updated version of the SoundEngine that people may find useful: http://stormyprods.com/SoundEngine/

Comment: I'd like to add that if you require Bones or Animation, managing a single POD file might be a better choice than OBJ/MTL.  Also, some people have switched to PVR from PNG for the lower memory footprint.  Remember, make your textures square!

Comment: +1 for writing or assembling it yourself the way you need it. It is always better if you understand the first layer below your actual game code very thoroughly.

Answer (score 10):

Yes. A quick google search shows:

- [cocos2d](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/)
- [Unity](http://unity3d.com)
- [Oolong Engine](http://oolongengine.com/)
- [Torque](http://www.garagegames.com/products/tge)

And others.

Comment: … others like Kobold2D (improved cocos2d): http://www.kobold2d.com

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Airplay SDK](http://www.airplaysdk.com/) which is a C++ cross-platform game SDK for iOS, Android, and 6 more mobile OSes. The code is compiled into native ARM binary. You even don't need a Mac to create and deploy your app, and there is a nice license for indies.

I have also heard of the [Esenthel](http://www.esenthel.com/) engine, which is a Windows/Mac engine that also supports iOS, according to their website. Looks like a one-man project though.

Comment: Another nice plus point of the Airplay SDK is that they also fully support Android. The engine is architected in such a way that the low-level guts of each platform are abstracted. So unless you're using device-specific features it's actually pretty trivial to develop a game on Android and iOS simultaneously.

Comment: Is AirplaySdk changed to Marmalade?

Comment: Yes, it was re-branded as Marmalade a few months ago.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [iPhone version](http://www.garagegames.com/products/torque-2d/iphone) of the [Torque Game Engine](http://www.garagegames.com/products/torque/tge/).

There is also:

- The [SIO2 Game Engine](http://sio2interactive.com/GAMES.html)
- [ShiVa](http://www.stonetrip.com/shiva/shiva-3d-game-engine.html)
- [Unity](http://unity3d.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use Cocos2d or role your own code. The apple sdk does not permit for third party sdk's and you would want to take advantage of the full resources of objective c in xcode anyway. Learn objective c it is not hard and it is getting miserable listening to all the web and javascripters out there trying to find an easy way when it couldn't be easier then Apples own tools.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
Cocos2d is a great one. I have used it frequently and it provide all what you need.
[www.cocos2d-iphone.org](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org)